# What is the most elegant way to implement text input field with custom set of valid keywords in JHipster?

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

My code draft does not display input even though everything seems in place:

**home.component.ts**

```
<p class="lead">Input: </p>
<div><jhi-calculator-input></jhi-calculator-input></div>
```

**calculator.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-calculator-input',
    template: `
            <input #calculatorInput pattern="/[0-9a\!\+\-\*]/" type="text" />
            <button (click)="calculate(calculatorInput.value)">Calculate</button>
            <div>{{calculatorInput.value}}</div>
    `
})

export class CalculatorComponent {
    calculate(inputValue: string) {
        return 'OK';
    }
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <p class="lead">Input: </p>
        <div><jhi-calculator-input></jhi-calculator-input></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
    </div>
</div>
```

The strange thing is that there are no errors in Chrome console and the template is not included into the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. The only thing I can think of is that you may have some other HTML in your home component that makes your jhi-calculator-input invisible. Modify the template of your home component to have only these two lines that you included in your post and see if it works.